# Stuck on Ubuntu loading after turning on my computer

Tags: boot

My computer is stuck on the loading screen and I’ve tried pressing crtl alt f1-4 and nothing comes on.

The boot up menu doesn’t show up even when the computer is turned off then on again.
Please help

Comment: What is the mainboard or computer type you are using? Can you enter the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the loading screen?" The manufacturer logo? The bios maker? The Ubuntu dots? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by unplugging my computer. Sorry for wasting your time.